# Cannot ping\trace win10 pc from android device via local network

Tags: networking, router, routing, ping

Local 5g wifi network 192.168.2.0/24

Android 5.1.1\CyanogenMod 12.1 device ip: 192.168.2.222 (ubeogesh-opo) (I use jackpal.androidterm to execute commands on it)

Windows 10 pc ip: 192.168.2.150 (ubeogesh-pc)

Windows firewall disabled, network discovery enabled (for all profiles)

Router IP: 192.168.2.1

Ping from PC to android:

```
Pinging 192.168.2.222 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.2.222: bytes=32 time=73ms TTL=63
```

Traceroute from PC to android:

```
Tracing route to ubeogesh-opo [192.168.2.222]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  router.asus.com [192.168.2.1]
  2   308 ms     1 ms     1 ms  ubeogesh-opo [192.168.2.222]

Trace complete.
```

Ping from android to PC:

```
PING 192.168.2.150 (192.168.2.150) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 192.168.2.150 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2002ms
```

Ping and tracepath from android to router:

```
22|u0_a72@A0001:/ $ ping 192.168.2.1
PING 192.168.2.1 (192.168.2.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.2.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=109 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=127 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=115 ms
^C
--- 192.168.2.1 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 109.158/117.387/127.349/7.526 ms
u0_a72@A0001:/ $ tracepath 192.168.2.1
 1:  ubeogesh-opo                                          0.323ms pmtu 1500
 1:  router.asus.com                                       1.907ms reached
 1:  router.asus.com                                      39.411ms reached
     Resume: pmtu 1500 hops 1 back 64
```

tracepath from android to PC:

```
tracepath 192.168.2.150
 1:  ubeogesh-opo                                          0.565ms pmtu 1500
 1:  no reply
^C
```

From router CP, i can ping both PC and Android:

```
traceroute to 192.168.2.150 (192.168.2.150), 30 hops max, 38 byte packets
 1  192.168.2.150 (192.168.2.150)  1.072 ms  *  1.391 ms

traceroute to 192.168.2.222 (192.168.2.222), 30 hops max, 38 byte packets
 1  192.168.2.222 (192.168.2.222)  109.768 ms  1.159 ms  1.015 ms

PING 192.168.2.150 (192.168.2.150): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.2.150: seq=0 ttl=128 time=2.087 ms

--- 192.168.2.150 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 2.087/2.087/2.087 ms

PING 192.168.2.222 (192.168.2.222): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.2.222: seq=0 ttl=64 time=259.913 ms

--- 192.168.2.222 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 259.913/259.913/259.913 ms
```

What bothers me most is that traceroute from pc to android includes router into the trace, i.e. disregarding both devices in the same network, hop goes to the router first anyway. I have tried checking routes on android device, but i can't read much from it:

```
130|u0_a72@A0001:/ $ ip route show
192.168.2.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.2.222
```

I've also tried explicitly adding a route to pc via the router, but it fails:

```
ip route add 192.168.2.150/32 via 192.168.2.1
Cannot talk to rtnetlink: Permission denied
```

What else can I check? Where could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a problem with my windows 10 pc. Other devices couldn't connect to it either. The problem was solved by resetting all network settings. Not a very precise\elegant solution (I wish I knew what was causing this), but it worked.

Here's what I did:

1. Go to win 10 settings
2. Go to status
3. Use the "Network reset" feature from there.

After reboot, the problem didn't reappear

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that SELinux preventing you (a shell user) to create a socket rtnetlink. 
so i suggest to try first to set selinux on permissive mode. it's not a trivial action, because you should root your phone and install an application like [SELinuxModeChange](https://jdrch.wordpress.com/2016/06/12/how-to-change-selinux-mode-from-enforcing-to-permissive/) to do it.